# Finding common columns position between files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I need to find the difference between two files in Unix,

**File 1:**

```
1,column1
2,column2
3,column3
```

**File 2:**

```
1,column1
2,column3
3,column5
```

I need to find the position of common column in file 2 from file 1 
If there is no matching column in file1 some default index value and column name should return.

**Output:**

```
    1,column1
    3,column3
   -1,column5
```

Can anyone help me to get in Unix script ?

Thanks,
William R

Comment: heard about [`diff`](http://man.cx/diff) or [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm)?

Comment: Why does "file2 - file1" contain "1,column1" ?

Comment: Sorry it's not difference , i have to find the common column position and write to another file.

Comment: Try to indicate what you want with representative examples with desired output. Also, indicate what you have tried so far. Why? Because otherwise the people answering will have to keep updating their answers any time you keep providing more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=1; next;} ($2 in a)' file2 file1
```

grep+process substitution:

```
grep -f <(cut -d, -f2 file2) file1
```

EDIT for updated question:

awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} {if ($2 in a) print a[$2]","$2; else print "-1," $2}' file1 file2 
# if match found in file1, print the index, else print -1
# (Also note that the input file order is reversed in this command, compared to earlier awk.)
```

grep:

```
cp file1 tmpfile #get original file
grep -f <(cut -d, -f2 file1) -v f2 | sed 's/.*,/-1,/' >> tmpfile #append missing entries
grep -f <(cut -d, -f2 file2) tmpfile # grep in this tmpfile
```

Comment: Thanks Very much but small help incase 3, column5 in File2(which is not matching in file1) in that case how can we indicate -1,column5 in output file.

Comment: Edit your question with example.

Comment: Please find the Edited question.